# JSON (jackson) passing parameter for serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

i have the following classes

```
public class Project extends Model {

public string name;
...

 public List<ParticipantStatus> participantStatuses = new ArrayList<ParticipantStatus>();

}
```

---

```
public class ParticipantStatus {
   String status;
}
```

i have the following array

```
User currentUser = getCurrentUser();
List<Project> projects = getAllmyProjects(currentUser);
```

i want to serialize projects array in the following maner:
for the given user i want all projects to show for participantStatuses array only status of the given user (i.e. currentUser) and not the whole array.

i.e. : if current user is "bob" i want the serialization to be:

```
[{"name":"projectA","status":"accepted"},{"name":"projectB","status":"declined"}]
```

how can i pass the user as a parameter for serializing array ?

Comment: Easiest thing to do would be to create an entity that represents a participant's status per project.

Comment: not clear how user is related to project ?

Comment: @Yagnesh user has project he is owner of and project he participates in.